# Big box Pella vs. Pella Pella

Tags: insulation, windows, energy-efficiency, replacement

The Pella salesman claims that his replacement windows are better than the Pella replacement windows that are sold at the big box stores.  Is that true?

I've done my best to ask the windows people at the big box probing questions.  Maybe I haven't found enough questions to ask.

So far, I've only found two differences:

1. Pella Pella: he says the frames have foam insulation added at the factory.  The big box window sales person says they can do that too, for $15 extra per window.
2. Pella Pella: he says that when they do the installation, they bring a small machine to put foam insulation into the wall around the edges.  The big box window installer says he uses the fiberglass kind and stuffs it in around the edges because the foam is too messy, and he says the results are the same.

Do either of those matter?  Also, what other differences are there?  What other questions should I ask?  I'm not looking to make my 1940's house a model of energy efficiency.  I just want to be more comfortable.  Money is a concern for me at this time.

The Pella Pella estimate is about double the big box Pella estimate.

Comment: Are you replacing the windows *just* to boost the insulation value? Or do you want new windows for other reasons as well? If the former, your money will go much further by increasing roof insulation, and/or thoroughly air sealing the house.

Comment: @LShaver - The existing windows are a disaster.  They are single pane glass and they are drafty.  There is a lot of aluminum which is also giving me a lot of heat loss.  There is no doubt I need to put something better in.  The question is, is there anything to be gained by paying double for the Pella Pella? // There is a second story which we don't use much.  That is already providing insulation from above.  I will think about wall insulation, rim joists, attic, etc., later.  First I've got to solve my window problem.

Comment: Double?!? no way that's worth it. Those two changes would give you a 20% boost in R-value at the absolute most (probably closer to 5%), on the weakest link in your envelope.

Comment: @LShaver - Are you saying the foam insulation with the small machine is significantly better than the batting stuffed in?  I can't get that from the big box installer.  I'd have to go with Pella Pella to get that.  But note, my wall insulation is not great to begin with.

Comment: In general I can say that _some_ manufacturers do make different quality of products and market those various models via different sales channels.  For instance, Target might have a special cheap model of Samsung TV that Best Buy would never sell, etc.  It's plausible, but could also just be sales puffery.

Comment: @JPhi1618 - Well put.  That's why I want to figure out what specific questions to ask, to compare.

Comment: The only places you're checking are big-box stores and well-advertised name brands. Both of them seem like ripoffs. I suggest casting a wider net.

Comment: Find a local community email list, Facebook group, or similar for your city or neighborhood, and ask for recommendations of local window installers. That's the best way to find someone who will do a good job and use good hardware.

Comment: Chances are your home has lower cost energy improvements, starting with air sealing the attic, and closing off the little used 2nd floor.  Get an energy audit / home performance contractor, or suitable non-profit, to get started.

Comment: @Bryce - No, that's not how I'm going to get started.  I have ancient, single pane windows, and they really do need to go.  If you can't help me with my question, it's not helpful for you to tell me I'm asking the wrong question.  You don't know my house.

Comment: As someone explained in response to a related question I asked, the key thing to ask turned out to be, "What is the U-factor for this window?" The standard 250 series with added foam insulation in the frame (added at the factory) is 0.28. The better 350 series with added foam insulation in the frame, and triple pane (which I will use in the bathroom, where I really want it toasty), is 0.17.

Answer (score 2):

First, to bust [a rumor](https://www.consumerreports.org/cro/news/2014/10/are-all-name-brand-products-sold-at-big-box-stores-the-same-as-those-sold-at-dealers/index.htm), if it's the same model/SKU, it's the same part. If you see a "549E" model at Home Depot, and a dealer also sells a 549E, then it's the real McCoy. However, they may well make a "547H" model that's been shaved for Home Depot (it may even be made by a different manufacturer.)

The big-box stores are very tough on vendors, on both price and return policy.  A such, many vendors build "Built for big-box" shaved models of their products, with cost-cutting shortcuts that they would never put into a dealer product.

Support and parts are nonexistent.  We get that stuff donated, and it's the same story - you call the dealer, they hear the model number and say  "That's a Home Depot special, there are no OEM parts for that." It's a throwaway.  The zero parts commonality suggests to me a different manufacturer altogether.

So is Pella making a shaved version of their window by the thousands for Home Depot?  Oh, very likely.  Hundreds of manufacturers do it.  Part of the deal is they show up on pallets, and obviously are *not* custom-fit.  Some replacement window manufacturers are able to build to your dimensions.

That said, it really pays to search for products more broadly than big-box stores and well-advertised "replacement window" manufacturers.  Both of them are complete ripoffs, and they are exploiting the fact that *you just don't know what else to do, and this seems easiest*.  They profit by seeming easiest.

Also, keep in mind the whole "replacement window" game *is itself* kind of a racket.  It's the nature of replacement windows to *need to be replaced* sooner than you'd like.

Comment: What causes you to say the replacement window “game”, as you call it, is a “racket”?  I’ve experienced excellent service and quality replacement windows, especially with Pella. Calling replacement windows and big box stores “ripoffs” seems outlandish.

Comment: @LeeSam This is broadly covered in the home improvement media.  Even [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/reginacole/2018/07/17/dont-buy-replacement-windows-for-your-old-house/#f5184862c0c5) has an article on it. I'm sorry if I inadvertently insulted your buying decision!

Comment: I don't plan to stay in this house for a long time.  But I need it warmer.  I have no kitchen window at all, just storms and some plexiglass I put up and caulked to keep it in place.  Where am I to look for this third option you allude to? The Pella at the big box is custom made at the factory to my dimensions.  It takes three weeks.  It's fine for you to make a systemic analysis, but how am I to make my house warmer?

Comment: @aparente001 I’d use replacement windows in your situation too. Forbes article focuses on expensive windows that don’t match the existing windows. Your situation is different. If you only have a storm window in place and you’re not going to be there too much longer, I’d use a replacement window from a local box store. You don’t need the most expensive and I doubt if it really needs to match the other windows. A new replacement window will make the house warmer.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica You should have read the Forbes article instead of just the headline. The Forbes article is by two people who do “refurbishing of old windows “. Of course they’re going to admonish replacement windows. The first half of the article is about replacement windows not “looking” the same as the original windows. Duh....  Then they discuss cost vrs. Payback. Hmmm...so it’s expensive...wow, shocker. I’d still like to know why replacement windows and big box stores are “ripoffs”, as you say.